# Subscript out of bounds error due to factors missmatch

Tags: r

I have this 2 datasets below and I run

```
library(caret)

confusionMatrix(data = heart_dec_pred, reference = test_data$target, positive = "Yes")
```

what i get is

```
`Error in `[.default`(data, , positive) : subscript out of bounds`
```

actually I do not understand that even my `heart_dec_pred` has levels 0 and 1 when I create it I get 1 and 2.

[image]

```
dput(heart_dec_pred)
structure(c(`1` = 2L, `2` = 2L, `3` = 2L, `4` = 1L, `5` = 2L, 
`6` = 2L, `7` = 1L, `8` = 2L, `9` = 2L, `10` = 2L, `11` = 2L, 
`12` = 2L, `13` = 2L, `14` = 2L, `15` = 2L, `16` = 2L, `17` = 2L, 
`18` = 2L, `19` = 2L, `20` = 2L, `21` = 2L, `22` = 2L, `23` = 2L, 
`24` = 2L, `25` = 2L, `26` = 2L, `27` = 2L, `28` = 2L, `29` = 1L, 
`30` = 1L, `31` = 2L, `32` = 2L, `33` = 2L, `34` = 2L, `35` = 1L, 
`36` = 2L, `37` = 2L, `38` = 1L, `39` = 2L, `40` = 2L, `41` = 1L, 
`42` = 2L, `43` = 2L, `44` = 2L, `45` = 2L, `46` = 2L, `47` = 2L, 
`48` = 2L, `49` = 2L, `50` = 2L, `51` = 2L, `52` = 2L, `53` = 1L, 
`54` = 1L, `55` = 2L, `56` = 2L, `57` = 1L, `58` = 2L, `59` = 1L, 
`60` = 1L, `61` = 1L, `62` = 2L, `63` = 1L, `64` = 1L, `65` = 1L, 
`66` = 2L, `67` = 1L, `68` = 1L, `69` = 1L, `70` = 1L, `71` = 1L, 
`72` = 1L, `73` = 1L, `74` = 1L, `75` = 2L, `76` = 1L, `77` = 1L, 
`78` = 1L, `79` = 1L, `80` = 1L, `81` = 1L, `82` = 1L, `83` = 1L, 
`84` = 1L, `85` = 2L, `86` = 1L, `87` = 1L, `88` = 2L, `89` = 1L, 
`90` = 1L, `91` = 2L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")
> dput(test_data)
structure(list(age = c(63, 41, 57, 57, 49, 50, 59, 44, 71, 59, 
51, 53, 54, 54, 65, 45, 53, 51, 44, 63, 48, 45, 54, 52, 29, 51, 
45, 67, 57, 53, 62, 53, 63, 42, 69, 50, 57, 64, 41, 46, 64, 41, 
39, 34, 74, 43, 76, 70, 60, 42, 35, 56, 67, 53, 48, 58, 54, 50, 
41, 51, 59, 46, 67, 65, 59, 57, 39, 61, 56, 62, 65, 70, 62, 35, 
47, 55, 51, 60, 35, 64, 56, 62, 67, 53, 49, 54, 58, 58, 57, 61, 
63), sex = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L), levels = c("1", "0"), class = "factor"), cp = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("3", "2", 
"1", "0"), class = "factor"), trestbps = c(145, 130, 120, 140, 
130, 120, 135, 130, 160, 150, 110, 130, 125, 135, 160, 104, 138, 
130, 108, 135, 122, 115, 108, 118, 130, 125, 128, 115, 132, 142, 
140, 130, 140, 120, 160, 110, 150, 140, 130, 105, 130, 112, 94, 
118, 120, 115, 140, 156, 150, 130, 122, 130, 160, 140, 110, 132, 
124, 140, 110, 130, 170, 150, 125, 110, 110, 128, 118, 145, 125, 
130, 138, 145, 120, 120, 108, 160, 140, 140, 126, 145, 132, 138, 
100, 123, 118, 122, 146, 136, 110, 148, 124), chol = c(233, 204, 
354, 192, 266, 219, 234, 233, 302, 212, 175, 197, 273, 304, 360, 
208, 234, 256, 141, 252, 222, 260, 309, 186, 204, 245, 308, 564, 
207, 226, 394, 246, 195, 240, 234, 254, 126, 313, 214, 204, 303, 
268, 199, 210, 269, 303, 197, 245, 240, 180, 192, 221, 286, 203, 
229, 224, 266, 233, 172, 305, 326, 231, 254, 248, 239, 229, 219, 
307, 249, 263, 282, 174, 281, 198, 243, 289, 299, 293, 282, 212, 
184, 294, 299, 282, 149, 286, 218, 319, 335, 203, 197), fbs = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("1", "0"), class = "factor"), 
    restecg = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", "0"), class = "factor"), 
    thalach = c(150, 172, 163, 148, 171, 158, 161, 179, 162, 
    157, 123, 152, 152, 170, 151, 148, 160, 149, 175, 172, 186, 
    185, 156, 190, 202, 166, 170, 160, 168, 111, 157, 173, 179, 
    194, 131, 159, 173, 133, 168, 172, 122, 172, 179, 192, 121, 
    181, 116, 143, 171, 150, 174, 163, 108, 155, 168, 173, 109, 
    163, 158, 142, 140, 147, 163, 158, 142, 150, 140, 146, 144, 
    97, 174, 125, 103, 130, 152, 145, 173, 170, 156, 132, 105, 
    106, 125, 95, 126, 116, 105, 152, 143, 161, 136), exang = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L
    ), levels = c("1", "0"), class = "factor"), oldpeak = c(2.3, 
    1.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 1.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 1.6, 0.6, 1.2, 0.5, 
    0, 0.8, 3, 0, 0.5, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.4, 0, 1.6, 0, 
    0, 1.2, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0.7, 
    0.2, 1.2, 1.1, 0, 0.9, 0, 0, 0, 1.5, 3.1, 1, 3.2, 2.2, 0.6, 
    0, 1.2, 3.4, 3.6, 0.2, 0.6, 1.2, 0.4, 1.2, 1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.4, 
    2.6, 1.4, 1.6, 0, 0.8, 1.6, 1.2, 0, 2, 2.1, 1.9, 0.9, 2, 
    0.8, 3.2, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0), slope = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("0", 
    "2", "1"), class = "factor"), ca = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("0", 
    "1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), thal = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L
    ), levels = c("0", "1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), target = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-91L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Comment: I would assume that `data` and `reference` must have identical factor levels and the value of `positive` must be one of these levels.

Comment: The values of 1 and 2 you see when you print heart_dec_pred are not the levels. It clearly says that "0"  and "1"  are the levels.

Comment: so what the error might be?

Comment: Please read what I have written. You have two user errors here: the factor levels of your two inputs are not identical and you misspecify the "positive" level.

Comment: but the factor levels are 0 and 1 for both so the positive is the error?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The levels seem to be identical. I got confused because of all the irrelevant data you shared.

Comment: Should it be `positive = "1"`?

Comment: `confusionMatrix(table(heart_dec_pred,test_data$target), positive = "1")` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(caret)
confusionMatrix(table(heart_dec_pred,test_data$target), positive = "1")

#> Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#> 
#>               
#> heart_dec_pred  0  1
#>              0 30  7
#>              1  9 45
#>                                          
#>                Accuracy : 0.8242         
#>                  95% CI : (0.7302, 0.896)
#>     No Information Rate : 0.5714         
#>     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 2.747e-07      
#>                                          
#>                   Kappa : 0.6387         
#>                                          
#>  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.8026         
#>                                          
#>             Sensitivity : 0.8654         
#>             Specificity : 0.7692         
#>          Pos Pred Value : 0.8333         
#>          Neg Pred Value : 0.8108         
#>              Prevalence : 0.5714         
#>          Detection Rate : 0.4945         
#>    Detection Prevalence : 0.5934         
#>       Balanced Accuracy : 0.8173         
#>                                          
#>        'Positive' Class : 1              
#>
```